# How to make scrollbar start from bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, scrollbar

All the code is in this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/EX6vs/366/

I have a simple chat, where I have a JS script that should work, it's onload in the body.

```
function updateScroll() {
    var element = document.getElementById("chatlogs");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}
```

In my real code, the function gets called when someone writes a new chat message, and the JS function works. I can't get it to work on load of the page though.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `window.onload = updateScroll;` ? Also select `No wrap - in <body>` as load type in your `fiddle`.

Comment: Your fiddle is set up wrong, hence why it is not working.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian, he should call the function right? updateScroll(), not just updateScroll

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: When setting scrollTop, first set a temp variable to the scrollHeight, 
you cannot set scrollTop to scrollHeight the way you have it.

Try this:

```
function updateScroll() {
        var element = document.getElementById("chatlogs");
        var elementHeight = element.scrollHeight;
        element.scrollTop = elementHeight
}
window.onload = updateScroll;
```

**Old Answer:**

Working Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/oqa12rht/

You need to start the function with:

```
window.onload = updateScroll();
```

You actually don't even need the `window.onLoad,`

you can just call the function like so:

```
    function updateScroll() {
            var element = document.getElementById("chatlogs");
            element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
    }


updateScroll();
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2j869L9o/

Comment: Guys still doesn't work with window.onload. Developer tools on Chrome give me this:
(index):51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of nullupdateScroll @ (index):51(anonymous function) @ (index):53

Comment: I also have Jquery in it but doesn't really have anything to do with the rest. 

As I said, Chrome gives me the problem I wrote in my last comment

Comment: doesn't work :/ Currently the JS is:

<script>

function updateScroll() {
        var element = document.getElementById("chatlogs");
        var elementHeight = element.scrollHeight;
        element.scrollTop = elementHeight;
}
window.onload = updateScroll;
</script>

Comment: Still doesn't work, the JS now is:

<script>

function updateScroll() {
        var element = document.getElementById("chatlogs");
        var elementHeight = element.scrollHeight;
        element.scrollTop = elementHeight;
}
window.onload = updateScroll;
</script>

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/fsfww0tx/
PS: dont put the same class and id on an html tag, you dont need to call updateScroll anymore, if we are calling it in the JS, so take that out too

Comment: Doesn't work. Could this be the reason? I have a jquery function that gets called whenever a user inputs some text. When inputed, I have this line:

    setTimeout(function(){ updateScroll(); }, 500);

So that the scrollbar goes down when a new message is in the chat (after 0.5 secs). This one works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107571/discussion-between-snowmate-and-omarjmh).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. I think it is the `fiddle` that is set up in a wrong way. Please find the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EX6vs/368/). All you have to do is, select `No wrap - in <body>` from the `javascript` toggle button.

@Omarjmh,

for `window.onload`, there is no need to execute the function. If you do so, the function will get executed and assign whatever it returns to onload. `()` should be excluded.

Here is what `MDN` says,

```
window.onload = funcRef;
```

`funcRef` is the handler function to be called when the window's load event fires.

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload